# Relation between a fixed point and being a well-order

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points, well-orders

I've been trying to prove the following, but with no particular success:

> Given a linear order $\leq$ on $A$, define $\pi:2^A\to 2^A$ by $X\mapsto\{y\in A: (\forall x < y)(x\in X) \}$. Let $A_0$ be the least fixed point of $\pi$. Prove that $x\in A_0$ iff $\{(a,b)\in A\times A: a\leq b < x\}$ is a well order.

For example, suppose that $\{(a,b)\in A\times A: a\leq b < y\}$ is a well order. I must prove that $y\in A_0$.

Here's my thought process: what does it mean that $y\in A_0$? $A_0$ is a fixed point for $\pi$ iff $A_0=\{y\in A:(\forall x < y)(x\in A_0)\}$. So the condition that $y$ lies in a fixed point $A_0$ means that $(\forall x < y)(x\in A_0)$. But to chech this condition, I'd need to check the sub-condition $x\in A_0$, which again means that $(\forall t < x)(t\in A_0)$, and now the same problem arises with checking the sub-condition $t\in A_0$...

Even setting this aside, I must use somehow that $\{(a,b)\in A\times A: a\leq b < y\}$ is a well order. So I'd think I need to guess some particular non-empty subset of $A$ that I need to consider, and then I need to take a least element in that subset. I don't really see which subset to consider, and how the "leastness" property would help.

For the other direction, I have the same problem as described at the beginning. When trying to use the condition that $y\in A_0$, an infinite chain of conditions arises...

Comment: Turning this sort of "infinite chain of conditions" into an actual proof is exactly what induction is for.

Comment: Do you mean transfinite induction on well-ordered sets? I still don't see how to apply it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reverse direction, since you have a well-ordering, you can use induction to turn your "infinite descending" argument into a proof that works.  That is, let $B=\{a\in A: a<y\}$ and then prove that $a\in A_0$ for all $a\in B$ by induction on $A$ (since you know $B$ is well-ordered by $\leq$).  In this proof by induction, you take $b\in B$ and get to assume every $a$ such that $a<b$ is in $A_0$, and want to prove $b\in A_0$ as well.  But this is immediate since the induction hypothesis exactly tells you that $b\in \pi(A_0)=A_0$.

(Notice that in this direction you *don't* use the leastness of $A_0$, only that it is a fixed point.  This shouldn't be surprising: since $A_0$ is the least fixed point, showing $y\in A_0$ is equivalent to showing that $y$ is in *every* fixed point of $\pi$, so all you should expect to use about $A_0$ in this proof is that it is a fixed point.)

For the forward direction, you'll need a different approach, since this time you do need to use the fact that $A_0$ is the *least* fixed point of $\pi$, rather than just that it is a fixed point.  (For instance, if you only knew it was a fixed point, then it could just be all of $A$, and $\leq$ certainly doesn't have to be a well order on all of $A$.)  So, how do you use an assumption like this?  Well, since it is the least fixed point, it is contained in any other fixed point.  So to show $A_0$ is contained in some other set, it's enough to just show that set is a fixed point.  That is, if $A_1$ is the set of all $x$ such that $\{(a,b)\in A\times A: a\leq b < x\}$ is a well order, if you can show that $\pi(A_1)=A_1$, then you can conclude that $A_0\subseteq A_1$.

Comment: The statement of transfinite induction that I know is this: suppose $W$ is a well-ordered set and $V$ is its subset. Further suppose that for all $w\in W$, if every $v < w$ lies in $V$, then $w$ lies in $V$. Then $W=V$. I think you're also using this version of the statement, but what is $W$ in your case? I can only see that $V=B$. Also, it seems you want to prove that $B\subseteq A_0$, but this version of transfinite induction claims that $W=V$. Maybe you're using a different version? I also can't see why $b\in \pi(A_0)$ (maybe it's because I don't understand what $W$ is).

Comment: And if $W=A$, then doesn't this prove that $A=B$, i.e., that every $a\in A$ is less than some fixed $y\in A$, which doesn't make sense?

Comment: Here $W$ would be $B$ and $V$ would be $A_0\cap B$.  So proving $V=W$ would prove that every element of $B$ is in $A_0$.

Comment: Thank you! But I still have a couple of questions: the assumption that every $a < b$ lies in $A_0\cap B$ only tells me that $a < y$ (i.e. $a\in B$) and $(\forall z < a) (z\in A_0)$ (i.e. $a\in A_0$, where I've used that $A_0=\pi(A_0)$). To show that $b\in A_0$,  I need to prove that $(\forall z < b) (z\in A_0)$. But I don't see how this immediately follows from the hypothesis. And another point, if I know that every element of $B$ lies in $A_0$, how does this help me with proving that $y\in A_0$? $y$ doesn't lie in $B$, so I can't use transitivity.

Comment: "$(\forall z < b) (z\in A_0)$" is the same as "every $a<b$ lies in $A_0\cap B$"--just change the variable name from $z$ to $a$.

Comment: To prove that $y\in A_0$, you just use the same argument one more time, once you know that $B\subseteq A_0$.  (This is the argument that you proposed in your original post: to show $y\in A_0$, you needed to show that $B\subseteq A_0$.)

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what you need to prove.  To prove it rigorously, you need to start with an arbitrary nonempty subset and choose a specific $y$ for which you can use the assumption to find a least element of that subset.